# 'Unable to connect to SQL Server database.' - webAPI

Tags: sitecore-api, webapi

**using:** VS-2017(as admin), sitecore-8.1.2 and SQL - 2012.

I created a ASP.Net web application - WebAPI to read content from my local sitecore instance.

In the "ValuesController.cs" I am using the below code.

```
// GET api/values
    public string Get()
    {
        var context = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");
        string itemPath = "/sitecore/content/Home";
        Sitecore.Data.Items.Item item = context.Items[itemPath,Sitecore.Globalization.Language.Predefined.English];
        return item.GetOuterXml(true);
    }
```

FYI - I copied all the app_config folder and added all .dll's into the project, from my local sitecore instance

Build-succeeded. When I try to run the project in IE/Chrome it's working fine, but if I trying to access this URL- http://localhost:1025/api/values I am getting the below error.
[image: SQL issue]

**with the stackTrace:**

> at System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.CreateMdfFile(String
>   fullFileName, String dataDir, String connectionString)    at
>   System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.EnsureDBFile(String
>   connectionString)    at
>   System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.GetConnection(String
>   connectionString, Boolean revertImpersonation)    at
>   System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider.IsUserInRole(String username,
>   String roleName)    at System.Web.Security.Roles.IsUserInRole(String
>   username, String roleName)    at
>   Sitecore.Security.Accounts.RolesInRolesProvider.IsUserInRole(User
>   user, Role targetRole, Boolean includeIndirectMemberships)    at
>   Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User.IsInRole(String roleName)    at
>   Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User.IsInRole(Role role)    at
>   Sitecore.Security.Accounts.Role.IsMember(Account account, Boolean
>   includeRoleMembers, Boolean includeEveryoneMembers)    at
>   Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.AccessRule.RuleAppliesToAccount(Account
>   account, Boolean includeRoleMembers, Boolean includeEveryoneMembers)
>   at Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.AccessRule.RuleApplies(Account
>   account, AccessRight accessRight, PropagationType propagationType,
>   Boolean includeRoleMembers, Boolean includeEveryoneMembers)    at
>   Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.AccessRule.IsMatch(Account account,
>   AccessRight accessRight, PropagationType propagationType,
>   AccessPermission permission, Boolean includeRoleMembers, Boolean
>   includeEveryoneMembers)    at
>   Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.AccessRuleCollectionHelper.GetMatchingRule(Account
>   account, AccessRight accessRight, PropagationType propagationType,
>   AccessPermission permission, Boolean includeRoleMembers, Boolean
>   includeEveryoneMembers)    at
>   Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.AccessRuleCollectionHelper.GetMatchingRule(Account
>   account, AccessRight accessRight, PropagationType propagationType)
>   at
>   Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.ItemAuthorizationHelper.GetItemAccess(Item
>   item, Account account, AccessRight accessRight, PropagationType
>   propagationType)    at
>   Sitecore.Buckets.Security.AuthenticationHelper.GetItemAccess(Item
>   item, Account account, AccessRight accessRight, PropagationType
>   propagationType)    at
>   Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.ItemAuthorizationHelper.GetAccess(Item
>   item, Account account, AccessRight accessRight)    at
>   Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.SqlAuthorizationProvider.GetItemAccess(Item
>   item, Account account, AccessRight accessRight)    at
>   Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.SqlAuthorizationProvider.GetAccessCore(ISecurable
>   entity, Account account, AccessRight accessRight)    at
>   Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.AuthorizationProvider.GetAccess(ISecurable
>   entity, Account account, AccessRight accessRight)    at
>   Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.AuthorizationManager.GetAccess(ISecurable
>   entity, Account account, AccessRight accessRight)    at
>   Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.AuthorizationManager.IsAllowed(ISecurable
>   entity, AccessRight right, Account account)    at
>   Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.ItemAccess.CanRead()    at
>   Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemProvider.ApplySecurity(Item item,
>   SecurityCheck securityCheck)    at
>   Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemProvider.GetItem(ID itemId, Language
>   language, Version version, Database database, SecurityCheck
>   securityCheck)    at
>   Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemProvider.GetItem(String itemPath, Language
>   language, Version version, Database database, SecurityCheck
>   securityCheck)    at
>   Sitecore.Data.Managers.PipelineBasedItemProvider.<>c__DisplayClass2f.b__2e()
>   at
>   Sitecore.Data.Managers.PipelineBasedItemProvider.ExecuteAndReturnResult[TArgs,TResult](String
>   pipelineName, String pipelineDomain, Func 1 pipelineArgsCreator,
>   Func 1 fallbackResult)    at
>   Sitecore.Data.Managers.PipelineBasedItemProvider.GetItem(String
>   itemPath, Language language, Version version, Database database,
>   SecurityCheck securityCheck)    at
>   Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemManager.GetItem(String itemPath, Language
>   language, Version version, Database database)    at
>   Sitecore.Data.ItemRecords.get_Item(String itemPath, Language language)
>   at Sitecore.WebAPI.Controllers.ValuesController.Get() in
>   C:\Users\sreddy1\Downloads\SitecoreSSCAndroid-master\Sitecore.WebAPI\Controllers\ValuesController.cs:line
>   20    at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )    at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.b__9(Object
>   instance, Object[] methodParameters)    at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object
>   instance, Object[] arguments)    at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)

**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to create REST api service in sitecore is using the ServiceAPI. Since you're using sitecore 8.1, you can create webapi services easily. Kindly follow below articles.

http://hookedon.digital/2015/12/03/leveraging-the-servicesapicontroller-part-1-implementing-a-sitecore-service-api-controller/

you can even customize the routes as follows.
http://hookedon.digital/2016/05/08/sitecore-service-api-controller-and-custom-routes/